# Nodejs exporting function that calls non exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is a curiosity type of question.

Assuming a file library.js as follows:

```
function alpha(){
    console.log("in alpha");
    beta();
    console.log("back in alpha");
}

function beta(){
    console.log("in beta")
}

module.exports = {
    alpha:alpha
}
```

When this library is required from another file say main.js then calling the alpha function from this module will look as follows:

```
var lib = require("library.js")
lib.alpha();

//outputs:
//in alpha
//in beta
//back in alpha
```

However the beta() function is not really exported. Does this mean NodeJS looks in the library.js file for beta()? If anyone could explain the process in technical detail it would be great.

Comment: Try rewriting your function and exposure slightly, to `exports.alpha = function() { /* Your alpha function */ }`, then declare your exports variable simply as `var exports = module.exports = {}`. Make sure to take out your current `module.exports` assignment.

Comment: @Defiant You should explain why you think the OP should that, because technique of the OP also works fine.

Comment: True, @t.niese. Just a style consideration to distinguish exposed from non-exposed functions. As for the OP's question, the calling of the function may be from another file but the execution is in the scope of this library; as so `beta()` is in the local scope.

Comment: @Defiant : the calling of the function may be from another file but the execution is in the scope of this library

This is what i was looking for. I suspected as much just wanted to make sure. I ll look around for more scope information like this, i m interested in understanding how node works in a low level. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Scope of the function, you can always call functions or variables from the same Scope or all surrounding Scope.
A Scope is usually a function-Statement and it is surrounded by maybe the global Scope (in Browsers the global Scope is window). You can nest functions and the inner functions have access to their own variables as well as the variables of their surrounding Scopes. Take a look at this example:

```
var varInGlobalScope = 'global'; // This is always accessible
var functionInGlobalNamespace = function () {
  // This is accessible inside the function 'functionInGlobalNamespace'
  // and all nested functions but not from the global Scope
  var varInFunction = 'in function';
  var functionInFunction = function () {
    // This is accessible inside the function 'functionInFunction'
    // but not from 'functionInGlobalNamespace' or the global Scope
    var varInFunctionInFunction = 'in function in function';

    console.log(varInFunctionInFunction); // works
    console.log(varInFunction); // works
    console.log(varInGlobalScope); // works
  }

  console.log(varInFunctionInFunction); // fails
  console.log(varInFunction); // works
  console.log(varInGlobalScope); // works
}

console.log(varInFunctionInFunction); // fails
console.log(varInFunction); // fails
console.log(varInGlobalScope); // works
```

This Scope is always there, this means if you build a function as a public member of another function and call a private Member from that it works. But if you are not in the correct Scope it fails. This behaviour is important if you extend the prototypes of an object.

```
var Demo = function () {
  var privateFunction = function () {
    console.log('private');
  };

  this.publicMethod = function () {
    console.log('public');
  };

  this.publicMethodToCallPrivateFunction = function () {
    privateFunction();
  };
}

Demo.prototype.tryCallingPublicMethod = function () {
  this.publicMethod();
};

Demo.prototype.tryCallingPrivateFunction = function () {
  privateFunction();
};

var demo = new Demo();
demo.publicMethod(); // works
demo.publicMethodToCallPrivateFunction(); // works
demo.tryCallingPublicMethod(); // works
demo.tryCallingPrivateFunction(); // fails
```

And now comes the "magic"-part of Node.js because if you build a module to require it in another module or file you have to put all exportable things into the special object `module.exports`. This is basically a object which is returned by the require function, but as we learned in the examples before the whole Scope of this function is still there.

There are a few other aspects which are maybe important in this handling, but to explain these will bloat the answer.

As a tip you can use this perfectly to implement private functionality and only provide a clean interface to the user. For example to split a huge function into several small chunks to maintain a clean code base.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing it up, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works it because of closure and hoisting.

First of all nodejs creates a surrounding block around the content of a file that looks like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

    function alpha(){
        console.log("in alpha");
        beta();
        console.log("back in alpha");
    }

    function beta(){
        console.log("in beta")
    }

    module.exports = {
        alpha:alpha
    }

});
```

Function declarations are always parsed before the code execution and always hoisted to top. So they are known by each other.

A function Definition like this:

```
 function beta(){
   console.log("in beta")
 }
```

can be seen as a shorthand for this:

```
 var beta = function beta(){
    console.log("in beta")
 }
```

With the difference that both the declaration and the definition of the function are hoisting to the beginning of the scope.

The resulting code will look this way:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
   var alpha, beta;

   alpha = function alpha(){
       console.log("in alpha");
       beta();
       console.log("back in alpha");
   }

   beta = function beta(){
       console.log("in beta")
   }

   module.exports = {
       alpha:alpha
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions which are not exported in the module, works as private method that can not be called from outside. They may only be used if some other function exported use it, else will be inaccessible code.